# How do i upgrade Xcode from 4.2.1 to 4.3.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Is there a way? I just need to run my app on my iPod which is 5.1 and my current version won't let me...?

Comment: Did you look for the update in the App Store application?

Comment: Are you running OS X Lion or above?

Comment: I haven't seen a way to just update, just install the latest version.

Comment: Hi i was in a similar situation as you over the weekend. quickly check out the steps i've written out for you in my post. and let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very simple. I came across the same problem over the weekend when I upgraded my iPad and iPhone to the latest iOS 5.1. The version of Xcode I had installed at that time was not able to run applications for my devices after the upgrade.

After doing a few things I was able to successfully run applications on my upgraded devices. Below I present a few simple steps for you to follow:

1) Download the latest version of Xcode which currently is 4.3.2 which includes SDKs for Mac OS X 10.7 Lion and iOS 5.1 suitable do install your application onto your iOS device

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12

2) During installation the installation window will ask you whether you would like to remove the previous version. Remove the previous version of Xcode and let it install the new version.

3) Once you have the latest version of Xcode installed you can run the Xcode application and open up your recent project.

4) Once you have your project opened, you may need to and certainly in my case I had to, code sign and point your project to the right development profile settings in the build settings.

5) Once all code signing is correct, on the top left you can select what you want to build to, make sure you have your iOS device connected and the button where it says iPhone simulator 5.1 to yourname's iphone

6) and then Xcode will build successfully onto your device

Answer (score 0):

Download it from the app store.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12

Comment: If you've already downloaded the latest and greatest, you don't have to download it again. The reason people are asking whether you are Lion or Snow Leopard is that the install process is different. So, are you running Lion or Snow Leopard? (Lion installs from the App Store and it's now pretty automatic; Snow Leopard you download the app and then have to manually install.)