# ios update to old version

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

I am using xCode 4.2 and my ipod is of version 4.1 I did not updated it because i need to know how my app works with the old ios. Recently i am having problem with the ios 4.1 so i decide to update my iPod. I have now idea how to update the device so opened the itunes and updated the device with the latest version. my iPod got the ios version 6.1.3.

now my problem start.

xCode can not recognize my ipod.

i was unable to restore my device to old version. iTunes shows me lots of different king of error message. like

> The iPod "iPod" could not be restored. This device isn't eligible for the requested build.

i even tried tinyUmbrella.

can anybody help me..
i want to bill my app on my device..

Comment: You need Xcode 4.6.x to work with iOS 6.1.x.

Comment: The question is why the Xcode does not recognize your iPod or how to downgrade the iPod to iOS4.1?

Answer (score 1):

The only way is upgrading your Xcode to **4.6 or Above**.

For upgrading your Xcode , please refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176785/how-do-i-upgrade-xcode-from-4-2-1-to-4-3-2)

Comment: for you kind information i am using mac os 10.6.8 i have no way to upgrade xcode.